# Error Loading "caret" library -> Requires "recipes" library -> Errors installing "recipes"

Tags: r

I installed caret specifying in the install that I wanted to install all dependencies as well. After that completed, I'm still having issues calling `dummyVars()` because I need to install `recipes`. I found this odd that this dependency was not already installed. I tried explicitly installing `recipes`, but received an error message. I am having a hard time decoding the error message. I don't know why this would have anything to do with where my libraries are being installed, and I do not think it is a problem with the repository.

```
> install.packages("recipes")
Installing package into ‘\\xxxxxxx/FolderRedirection/xxxxxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
recipes  0.1.6  0.1.7             FALSE

installing the source package ‘recipes’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/recipes_0.1.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 989183 bytes (965 KB)
downloaded 965 KB

* installing *source* package 'recipes' ...
** package 'recipes' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in findpack(package, lib.loc) : 
  there is no package called 'recipes'
Calls: <Anonymous> -> findpack
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'recipes'
* removing '\\xxxxxxx/FolderRedirection/xxxxxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/recipes'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCACRGQ\downloaded_packages’
> dummies <- caret::dummyVars(~ loan_type, data = df)
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘recipes’
```

Comment: Uninstall caret. Ensure you have RTools(updated). It is assumed from the paths that you're using Windows. Finally, try reinstalling caret with dependencies set to `TRUE` ie `install.packages("caret",dependencies=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thank you, I uninstalled `caret`, reinstalled the latest stable version of RTools and reinstalled `caret` via `install.packages("caret", dependencies = TRUE)`. Still receiving an error: ```> ohe_feats = c('loan_type')
> dummies <- caret::dummyVars(~ loan_type, data = df)
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘recipes’
> dummies <- dummyVars(~ loan_type, data = df)
Error in dummyVars(~loan_type, data = df) : 
  could not find function "dummyVars"```